# iOS10 - Call background web-services in Siri Intent Extension to fetch data and show it to user

Tags: ios, ios10, siri, sirikit

in iOS 10 Is it possible to call web-service in Siri Intent Extension to fetch some data from server and show response via Siri?

I want to implement Siri in our App, so when user do the inquiry or search for something, our app listen to user commands and will fetch the results via web-service call to show results/output to users.

Can we customize SMS or Payment Intent for the app to listen user commands related to Messaging or Payment so we process some parameters or keywords in the command and handle it ourselves.

Comment: Have you read https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/ ? It answers your questions.

Comment: @rocky, yes i read the documentation and implemented accordingly.  The issue was when i was calling a webservice in intent handler then Siri was timing out and was reseting to listen new command without waiting for response.

Comment: I am running into the same issue. The API call doesn't finish in time, and I get nil or "private" results. How did you solve this issue?